# Graph theory in public transportation

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, graph

[image]

Hi,

I am now developing public transportation guide software. In Europe an US Google Map provides this but in Turkey it does not.  I have database which contains all stations’ latitudes and longitudes, and other bus- line, station information. In my plan, firstly I will use graph theory (stations are vertexes; edge weights are distances among stations) and connect stations which are on the same bus-line; then find routes. After that I will demonstrate route on Google Map. I have accomplished the first step, connecting stations. However, after that I found a mistake in my plan which is shown in the figure. 
Person wants to go near A to K, the program should say

1. Walk to station A
2. Got on bus 8 at station A
3. Got off bus 8 at station E
4. Walk to station H
5. Got on bus 970 at station H
6. Got off bus 970 at station K

But, there is no connection between station E and H. So, graph algorithm cannot find a route from A to K. I should define a walk path between E and H. However this is only small demonstration of the city there are over 6500 station in the city. How can I solve this problem?
I have an idea that add connections between stations with in 1km range; but I think that it is inefficient.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could compare distances between the 2 lines stations and select the closest 2 stations by walking? The [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) could be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but it works only passenger use 2 buses. What if 2 lines does not intersect and third line or fourth lines needed?

Comment: What about https://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/ ? It seems there are already a few lines in Turkey.

Comment: @MrUpsidown it only shows subway lines in Turkey. There is only one subway line in İzmir.

Comment: The point is that you can contribute to it...

Answer (score 0):

Add a directed edge between E and H with weight say 'a'. Choose 'a' in such a way that none of the edge weights in your network have the same weight 'a'. For example, you can choose 'a' to be 0 as I am sure none of the edges in your network have weight zero as that would mean there is no distance between some two stations. Next, code your program in such a way that whenever there is a route selected that contains an edge with weight 'a', then the program should say, "*Walk from station E to station H*" or whichever nodes the edge with weight 'a' connects.

Otherwise, you can have a graph such there are two directed edges from one node to another whenever you have to walk. Say one edge is weighted 0 and the other by the distance between the two stations. Make sure your program is coded in such a way that when there are two edges encountered between say stations A and B, one with weight 0 and the other with say 'x', then the program gives the instruction, "*Walk from station A to B, a distance of 'x' km.*"